# Running gnuplot on java

Tags: java, gnuplot

I´m  running a java project using gnuplot to generate charts in pdf but I want to save those files in another folder outside my working directory. Is that possible?

I have this for now

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnuplot test.gp");
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }

        proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a command-line flag for gnuplot to save output in a different directory. That is unrelated to Java (or programming)

Comment: Without seeing `test.gp` it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

In gnuplot console check `help command line options`. There is the option `-e`.

You need to have the following argument for `exec()` in Java.

```
"gnuplot -e myOutput='<YourPDF>' test.gp"
```

where you have to replace `<YourPDF>` with your path. Since I do not know Java, the Java-people have to tell you how you get this done.

A minimal gnuplot script would for example look like the following:

```
set term pdfcairo
set output myOutput
plot sin(x)   # or whatever
set output
```